# How can make text output easy and shortly?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, find, output

I want modify some text file. But My script too long.

How can make short? who can advise about my script.

I want made loop `acap = line[4] ucap = line[5] ucp = line[6] saved = line[8]` value like `tcap`.

below is my script.

```
with open("find_c_volume_show.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "%" in line:
            line = line.split(',')
            vser = line[0]
            vol = line[1]
            aggr = line[2]
            node = line[7]

            if 'TB' in line[3]:
                tcap = str(line[3].split("TB")[0])
                tcap = float(tcap) if '.' in tcap else int(tcap)
            elif 'GB' in line[3]:
                tcap = str(line[3].split("GB")[0])
                tcap = (float(tcap) if '.' in tcap else int(tcap) /1024)
            elif 'MB' in line[3]:
                tcap = str(line[3].split("MB")[0])
                tcap = (float(tcap) if '.' in tcap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024)
            elif 'KB' in line[3]:
                tcap = str(line[3].split("KB")[0])
                tcap = (float(tcap) if '.' in tcap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024 /1024)
            elif 'B' in line[3]:
                tcap = str(line[3].split("B")[0])
                tcap = (float(tcap) if '.' in tcap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024 /1024 /1024)
            else:
                print ("Please check script.")

            if 'TB' in line[4]:
                acap = str(line[4].split("TB")[0])
                acap = float(acap) if '.' in acap else int(tcap)
            elif 'GB' in line[4]:
                acap = str(line[4].split("GB")[0])
                acap = (float(acap) if '.' in acap else int(tcap) /1024)
            elif 'MB' in line[4]:
                acap = str(line[4].split("MB")[0])
                acap = (float(acap) if '.' in acap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024)
            elif 'KB' in line[4]:
                acap = str(line[4].split("KB")[0])
                acap = (float(acap) if '.' in acap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024 /1024)
            elif 'B' in line[4]:
                acap = str(line[4].split("B")[0])
                acap = (float(acap) if '.' in acap else int(tcap) /1024 /1024 /1024 /1024)
            else:
                print ("Please check script.")

            if 'TB' in line[5]:
                ucap = str(line[5].split("TB")[0])
            .....

            if 'TB' in line[6]:
                ucp = str(line[6].split("TB")[0])

            .....

            if 'TB' in line[8]:
                saved = str(line[8].split("TB")[0])

            .....
            line = vser, vol, aggr, tcap, acap, ucap, ucp, saved
    print (line)
```

I want match to TB capacity format in text.
below is my text file.

```
Vserver,Volume,Aggregate,Total,Avail,Used,UsedP,Node,Saved
FAS8040-ZZZZ,vol0,Node1_aggr0,466.6GB,436.0KB,30.60MB,6%,FAS8040-ZZZZ,0B
FAS8040-YYYY,vol0,Node2_aggr0,46.6GB,428.6KB,38.07B,8%,FAS8040-YYYY,23KB 
FAS8040-XXXX,vol0,Node1_aggr0,466GB,436.0GB,30.60GB,6%,FAS8040-XXXX,44GB
FAS8040-AAAA,vol0,Node2_aggr0,466.6TB,428.6MB,38.07MB,8%,FAS8040-AAAA,102MB
```

Comment: `elif 'GB':`, do you mean `elif 'GB' in line[3]:` ?

Comment: Too long for what? It is 30 lines long, what is the problem?

Comment: When you say your script is too long, do you mean too many lines of code, or do you mean that it is too slow?

Comment: I think you could simple it, but it wont be any difference. 25 lines or 30 are the same...

Comment: I edit my question. My script will be add if loop for `ucap = line[5] ucp = line[6] saved = line[8]`. Please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help get you started:

```
unit = ['TB', 'GB', 'MB', 'KB', 'B']
with open("find_c_volume_show.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "%" in line:
           line = line.split(',')
           out = []
           for l in line[3:6] + [line[8]]:
             try:
               ind = [unit[i] in l for i in range(5)].index(True)
             except ValueError:
               print('please check script')

             val = str(l.split(unit[ind])[0])
             out.append(float(val)/1024**ind)

           line = line[0:3] + out[:-1] + line[6:8] + [out[-1]]
           print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I can't made result. that script not work. please explain your script. I can't understand `line = line[0:3] + out[:-1] + line[7] + out[-1]`

Comment: Hi, yes I made some changes, this should work better. The line you mention just concatenates multiple lists into one list. The `+` operator in python for `list` just performs concatenation. Note that this line of code had a error, I corrected it in the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: I add output script that code. But that make error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.sum_data.py", line 70, in <module>
    f.write(line +'\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
`

I add this script in print position.
`f = open("mod_c_vol_size.txt", 'w')
        f.write("Vserver,Volume,Aggregate,Total,Avail,Used,UsedP,Node,Saved\n")
        f.write(line +'\n')
f.close()`

Comment: you are adding `'\n'` which is a string to `line` which is a list. To fix this, do the following: `f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')`

Comment: Thank you. But error occurred `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.sum_data.py", line 70, in <module>
    f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected string, float found
`

Comment: Ah. Well, if you want to write the line to a new file, each item in the `line` list needs to be converted to a string. You can either do it explicitly where when you converted some items to floats, you can convert them to strings again i.e. `out.append(str(float(val)/1024**ind))`, or possibly better would be to use string formatting, something like `('{},'*8).format(*line)`. You can look up `format` method for string to get a list of string formatting options.